# consul: how many agents for services

Tags: consul

I am playing a little with Docker and Consul and i have a couple of questions regarding agent-service mapping especially in docker environment. Assume i have a service name "myGreatService" being simple web nodejs helloworld application encapsulated with docker image named "myGreatServiceImage". From Consul docs i did understand that when you register a service (through HTTP or service definition file) than  service is about to be "wired" to agent/consul node (the wired node can be retrieved via /v1/catalog/service/). So if a consul node is  down (or node health check decided it is down) than all services "wired" to that consule node will automatically be marked as down. Am i right ?

If i run my GreatServiceImage image multiple times on a single host via docker (resulting of multiple instances of "myGreatService" service) 
how many agents shall I run ? 
A single per host managing all containers (all service instances) on that host? Or maybe a separate agent for each container (service instance) ?

Comment: in production, it's recommended to run consul in the cluster mode (3-5 servers) so when a (consul) node fails, the cluster is still available, and service definitions readable. it's a distributed system, so in this setup, all nodes have all the data, so your service isn't 'wired' to a particular consul node.

Answer (score 6):

If a health check for a service fails then the service will be marked as down and won't show up if you do a DNS query for that service

```
dig @localhost -p 8500 apache.service.consul
```

If you do a call to the api you will see that the service is still listed. This is because the service is not removed, it is just marked as down. If you would do an api call to check the health of that service it would be shown as down.

```
curl localhost/v1/catalog/service/apache
curl localhost/v1/health/service/apache
```

You can add the ?passing flag to that last call to recieve only the healthy services. (just like the dns query)

```
curl localhost/v1/health/service/apache?passing
```

If the consul agent on the host fails then all services running on that host won't show up if you query consul for the services. (either via a dns query or via the api).

As for the number of agents you should be running: Run one consul agent per host. Let your services register themselves via the api of your local consul agent. (or preconfigure all your services in the config files, but I recommend you to make this a dynamic process of self registering)

Comment: For clarification: what do you mean by "agent/node on the host" You meant that agent/node  that did "register" a service (and you can see the exact one from a response to /v1/catalog/service/ call) fails than any services  wired to that agent/node simply disappear from consul registry (not visible from API and DNS) ? Can you confirm, pls

Comment: By agent/node on the host I meant the consul agent running on the host. If you register a service on a certain consul agent and that agent goes down, then you will not be able to fetch that service using either the consul api or dns.

Comment: Great. Thx for clarification. As i am much more running consul in Docker the  i always need explicit explanation what one means by "running agent on host"

Comment: You can run consul [Inside a docker container](https://github.com/progrium/docker-consul) or directly on your server.  That's up to you. I would suggest you to take a look at [registrator](https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator) as well.

Comment: Yes, I know. I have been using registrator as well